# Worksheet_change event and slicer filter connection conflict

Tags: excel, vba, events, slicers

I have a problem that is breaking my head for a couple of days now, so I decided to share it with you, maybe you already stumbled upon the same problem.

=== this is the context: ===

I'm working on this excel file where I have, among other, these three tabs:
- one, called "Data", where I store the data I need for the file in a regular table;
- the second, called "Chart_1", where one can find pivot_table_1 and chart_1. The source for these objects is in "Data" tab.
- the third tab is called "Chart_2" and contains pivot_table_2 and chart_2. These objects are also sourced from "Data" tab.
I have five slicers in tab "Chart_1" and another five in tab "Chart_2". All the slicers are connected to both pivot_tables found in the "Chart*" tabs.
I used VBA for the charts formats in the tabs, as Worksheet_Change events.

=== this is the problem: ===

When I select something in the slicer (whichever is the "Chart*" tab), it always activates "Chart_2".
If I click in one of the slicers in tab "Chart_1", when the macros finish running, tab "Chart_2" is activated.
When I click in one of the slicers in tab "Chart_2", everything is fine because the activated tab doesn't change.
Whichever slicer I use (whatever tab is it embedded in), VBA always runs first "Chart_1"'s Worksheet_Change and then "Chart_2"'s Worksheet_Change. I think this is happening because of the filter connections: when I click in one slicer, it will trigger all affected Worksheet_Change events.

=== this is what I already tried: ===

- have a global variable where I store the name of the correspondent tab of the work. Didn't work because both macros from both tabs are executed. I tried the same with a counter and failed likewise.
- look for a OnClick event where I could save the name of the tab where I clicked for the last time prior to the "Chart*"'s macros run. Didn't find any OnClick event, buh.
- I thought about having a global variable to store the name of the sheet of the slicer I clicked/selected the last time, but I don't know how to get it. Do you think this could work? How can I implement it?

So, this is my logic/programming problem, right now. Do you have any suggestion on how can I fix it? I just want to stay in the tab where I was when I clicked the slicer...

Comment: "Whichever slicer I use (whatever tab is it embedded in), VBA always runs first "Chart_1"'s Worksheet_Change and then "Chart_2"'s Worksheet_Change" Is this intended? i.e. Do you want both charts to update when you use either slicer? It makes sense for both macros to trigger if both sheets change. If you do not want this, does removing the connection of the slicers to the sheet it is not on fix the issue? Or are you simply looking for a way to ".activate" which ever sheet you were on before adjusting the slicers?

Comment: If so, You could, for this specific case and because chart1 always gets called first maybe do the following with a golabl variant: `GoodNameForAVariable = activesheet.name` in the begining of chart1s change event and then at the end of chart2s change event: `Thisworkbook.Sheets("GoodNameForAVariable").activate`

Comment: @Czeskleba, yes, it's intended that both macros run. I want to update both charts at the same time when I use the slicer. I also tried to remove the connections and connect the slicers of each sheet only to the other objects in the same sheet, but it didn't work also, because the connections that I ticked in one tab were mimicked to the other tab.
That's exactly what I'm looking for: to activate the sheet i were on before adjusting the slicers! :)

Comment: I just build a sheet a little like yours. my way works buuuut just changing the a slicer and triggering a change event on another sheet does not by itself activate that sheet. I suspect you have something IN your code that actually switches sheets. Maybe you can avoid that. if you can't my code should work nonetheless.

Comment: @Czeskleba, when I adjust the slicer (whether in "Chart_1" or "Chart_2" tab), the VBA events always start by chart1 macro and then chart2 macro.
So, we would have this:
- I click any slicer in any of the tabs;
- Chart_1 macro runs;
- Chart_2 macro runs;
- Both tabs are updated;
- Chart_2 is activated, no matter what.

So: if I fill the GoodNameForAVVariable global variable when I start macro 1, the Thisworkbook.Sheets("GoodNameForAVariable").activate line will activate the Chart 1. But if I started on Chart_2 tab, it will also activate Chart_1 tab, so it won't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

Chart1-Sheet:

```
Public GoodNameForAVariable As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

GoodNameForAVariable = ActiveSheet.Name

'Your code happens here

End Sub
```

Chart2-Sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Your code happens here

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(GoodNameForAVariable).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, THIS WWWWWOOOOOOORKEEEEEEEEED!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot, Czeskleba!